# Strange Indentation

Tags: modeling, mesh

Man, I hope this has an easy fix. As I'm sculpting and shift from object mode to edit mode, I notice a strange indent in the character's forehead (I call it the "bullet-hole". This only appears when I go into object mode. Once in edit mode, it disappears. How can I get rid of that bullet-hole?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, From the screenshots its hard to tell what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: maybe an inner face?

Answer (score 2):

Your model has a very uneven mesh, with big NGons on the top. When sculpting you move individual vertices around. This area does not have many vertices to move, so the effect is very immediate. To solve this do the following:

1. Add more geometry, preferably very evenly
2. Get rid of your NGons